# Where to place images/text on a page in design?

Tags: page-layout, composition

I’m new to graphic design and web design and one thing I’ve always wanted to figure out is WHERE to place my text and images on page to create a balanced and aesthetically pleasing layout and composition? What are the best spots on a page to place text and images in a balanced way ? It’s something I’m currently struggling with I will set up a document put a grid on it and don’t know what to do from there I don’t know if the image should go to left or the right etc

Any help?

Comment: This question covers a very broad discussion. It would be better to actually put some of your images and texts on a page and then ask for specific feedback about placement for balance and interest. Without knowing what you are actually trying to create and what you are working with, it is difficult to assist you in your layout. There are not really any hard rules like images go on the left and text on the right...

Answer (score 1):

This is a **very** broad question with no possible definitive answer, but...

In general, any "best spot" for *anything* relies on *what* the "thing" is
 and what the **goal** of the design may be.

Design, more specifically layout, is a **"jigsaw puzzle"** you have to figure out.

You have the pieces but you don't *really* know where they fit. If you're sitting in front of a blank document in some computer software, that can make figuring out where the pieces go **much** more difficult when starting out. This is why it's often best to step away from any electronic device, grab a pen and paper and start some rough sketching. The **best** design ideas are not born in some layout software.

Yes, I'm aware using "paper" is almost blasphemous nowadays for some. However, ideas flow *much* more freely when sketching than they *ever* will when constrained by software. If you *really* don't want to use paper, then use some tablet with painting software to sketch - with a pen, stylus, or finger **NOT** a mouse.

The important aspect is to NOT use layout software for ideation.  Being able to quickly scribble a square where an image may fall, and a few lines where text may go is much more fruitful than moving image/text frames around in an application. All layout software does is *constrain* you. You are *forced* to "create" how the software makes you create - always rigid verticals and horizontals, perfect shapes, etc. - as opposed to forcing the software to implement what you *want* to implement.

In addition, with sketching, within a couple minutes you can have 10-15 different rough sketch.. you can then compare the sketches, find one which feels like it's working better than the others and refine it. Where as in software, the tendency is to just keep moving things around on the *same* page... you *lose* any past ideas and just keep "poking at the darkness" *hoping* a light is going to reveal itself. There may have been a decent idea 20 minutes ago, but you've moved everything around and no longer even remember what it was.

In terms of *where* things may be placed....

One typically thinks of eye movement and importance. You have to think to yourself....

- What is the goal of this design?
- What is most important for the viewer to ingest?

Then, you calculate how a person's eye may move across a page.

- What's the first thing you want a viewer will see? The last thing?
- Do they see the most important thing first?
- It is clear to the viewer what is being asked or promoted?
- What will the viewer remember 10 seconds *after* seeing the design?

From here, a design starts to consider balance and proximity.

- Is the visual path across all the elements easy to follow?
- Does placement of elements make the design seem or "feel" chaotic?
- Does the percieved visual movement cause the viewer to linger anywhere?
- Does the viewer linger where you want them to?

**Regarding grids**.... There's **no** rule which states you **must** use any grid. Grids can be helpful for *some* designs, but often grids are merely restraints you are placing upon yourself -- again, why a pen and paper can be much better at times. My 2¢... find the design, *then* worry if it fits into any grid. Don't "design to a grid". There are *very* successful designers which *never* bothered with any "grid". Use them if they are *helping* but *never* feel you "must" use a grid.

For me, grids are only ever truly beneficial for web design (since browsers have an inherent grid you *must* conform to) or text-heavy documents such as books, multi-page sales letters, brochures etc. Where one wants the eye movement between pages to be percieved as smooth and *not* feel sporadic or chaotic. But even then, I *design first* and *then* adjust to match a grid. I don't "design to a grid". For one pages such as fliers, posters, etc. or single viewed items I generally ignore grids entirely.